# How to render Gtk.DrawingArea() in a Gtk.Treeview()?

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm having some problems to render a `Gtk.DrawingArea()` in to a `Gtk.TreeView()`. Is this possible?

So far I have this code:

```
window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

darea=Gtk.DrawingArea()
darea.modify_bg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.Color(1,1,1))

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(Gtk.DrawingArea)
liststore.append([darea])
liststore.append([darea])
treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
window.add(treeview)

treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Drawing Areas")
treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)

cellrenderer = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf() #Gtk.Drawable() #Gtk.CellRendererText()
treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cellrenderer, True)
treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderer, "d areas", 0)

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

But ofcourse it doesn't works because I'm trying to render it with a `Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()`. Is there any kind of`Gtk.CellRendererDrawingArea()` ?

Comment: Where does the drawing area come from? If you are doing the drawing yourself anyway, why not implement a custom cell renderer?

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah the drawing is me who makes it. I wanted to make my own cellrender but I just found C docs, I guess I'll take a good luck to that

Comment: The idea behind `GtkTreeView` is to maintain a clear separation of the data and the UI; the store (model) contains data that the renderers know how to render. The model is not designed to contain widgets, and the tree view is not a container that can embed them, so there is no renderer that will display an arbitrary widget. Since you already know how to draw the data, you need to create a custom renderer instead of a drawing area. Inherit from Gtk.CellRenderer and do the drawing in its render virtual method, by implementing the `on_render` method, along with `on_get_size`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for those big lines! along with this [this examples](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq13.045.htp&req=edit) I'll probably be capable of doing this :)

Comment: OK, I've now posted an expanded version of the comment as an answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind `GtkTreeView` is to maintain a clear separation between the underlying data (*model*) and the user interface (*view*). The tree store only contains data, with renderers being independent objects that know how to display the model data. Typically a renderer's property is connected to a column of the data model using the `add_attribute` method of `GtkTreeViewColumn`. For example, to render the first column of the model as text, one would instantiate a text renderer and call `textcolumn.add_attribute(textrenderer, "text", 0)`.

Your code cannot work because there is no cell renderer that displays arbitrary widgets. Neither is the model designed to host GUI objects, nor is the tree view a widget container. The tree view is designed to be able to scale to tens of thousands of rows, which cannot be accomplished using a separate widget for each cell.

In your case, as you already know how to draw the data, it should be straightforward to create a custom renderer and use it to draw the column instead of trying to embed a drawing area into the tree view. Inherit from Gtk.CellRenderer and do the drawing in its `render` virtual method, by implementing the `on_render` method, along with `on_get_size`.

Comment: I just want to point out that your argument "The tree view is designed to be able to scale to tens of thousands of rows, which cannot be accomplished using a separate widget for each cell" is just wrong and always have been. All other modern GUI toolkits create this widgets on the fly now. But unfortunately even in GTK4 there is no plan to support a recycler list widget because GTK lacks the financial and personal support to implement it.

Comment: @Lothar Creating widgets on the fly makes sense; I was referring to having all the widgets created in advance, as in a `VBox` or similar.